# Trying to figure out why my bot wont send an embed to the channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a script that sends an embed via a webhook, it works just fine but I am trying to convert it to send via the bot into the same channel. I cant seem to figure that out (I have never used the bot to send embeds before.)

```
async def start(keyword):

SOME CODE HERE

    await embeded(channel)

async def embeded(channel):
    # Discord Embed Setup   
    embed = Embed(
        description=f"[**eBay Link**]({eBayLink})",
        color=0x0d0d22,
        timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
        )

    embed.set_author(name=Titles)
    embed.add_field(name='Average', value=Averages, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Lowest', value=Lowests, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Highest', value=Highests, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Margin', value=Margins, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Postage', value=Postages, inline=True)

    embed.set_footer(text='TEST', icon_url='IMAGE')

    embed.set_thumbnail(image.get_attribute('src'))

    await channel.send(embed=embed)

    print("Embed sent to discord!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!flip '):
        keyword = message.content.split('!flip ')[1]
    await start(keyword, channel)

client.run(token)
```

I get the error

```
    await start(keyword, channel)
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined
```

Comment: Where do you want to send the embed?

Comment: The same channel that the command was made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to add `channel` parameter to the function also.
2. You should pass `message.channel` instead of `channel`.
3. Indent `start` function in the `if` statement of `on_message`.

Function Edits:

```py
async def start(keyword, channel):
    #Code
    await embeded(channel)
```

on_message Edits:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!flip '):
        keyword = message.content.split('!flip ')[1]
        await start(keyword, message.channel)
```